# how to debug RDLC when data shows in code but does not show up in RDLC in preview mode

Tags: rdlc, dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am encountering an issue with an RDLC report I'm working on. The data for the report shows up perfectly fine in Visual Studio Code during design time, but when I run the report and view it in RDLC's preview mode, the data doesn't appear. I've tried to identify the problem on my own but haven't been successful so far.

Here are the relevant details of my RDLC report setup:

Dataset: I have verified that the dataset used in the RDLC report is the same one I'm using in Visual Studio Code, and it contains the necessary data.

Data Binding: The dataset is correctly bound to the report elements.

Data Source Connection: The data source connection is consistent between Visual Studio Code and the RDLC report.

Parameters: The report utilizes parameters, and I have checked that they are being passed correctly from the application code.

Data Filters: I have reviewed the data filters applied to the dataset in the RDLC report and confirmed they are not excluding the data I expect to see.

Layout and Design: The layout of the RDLC report seems fine, and there are no overlapping elements hiding the data.

Output Formats: I have tried exporting the report to different formats, and the data still doesn't appear.

Logging: I have enabled logging and error handling in my application, but no errors or exceptions related to the RDLC report are being logged.

Data Types and Formatting: I have made sure that the data types and formatting in the RDLC report match the data being passed.

RDLC Preview Modes: I've tried different preview modes within Visual Studio, but the issue persists.

I'm using Visual Studio and the RDLC report is defined in the 'StandardSalesCreditMemo.rdlc' file.

Any help or suggestions to debug this issue would be greatly appreciated. If you need any more information or code snippets, please let me know, and I'll be happy to provide them.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!